# What is the best way to print an action figure?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

I have created an action figure and would like to print it.
Anyway, I am not sure the best way to print it, the action figure can be printed only once but the duration is 10 hours. If I separate the part, the time is concise, but I need to do some changes to my file. What is the best way to print an action figure?
If the second method is the better (separate arm, legs, etc.), does exist a good way to do the join between parts?

My 3d printer is Elegoo Mars, so I use Chitubox.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a photo/screenshot of your action figure?

Comment: Yes, I can share it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printing a complex object like this one from an attached photo requires a few factors to consider, such as print time, quality, ease of printing and eventual post-processing. You have two options: print the entire figure in one piece with supports, or separate the parts and print them individually.

**Printing the entire figure in one piece** can be a good option if you want to save time and reduce the amount of post-processing work. If you decide to go with this option, make sure to orient the model correctly to minimize the need for supports and reduce the risk of failure during printing.

**Separating the parts and printing them individually** can allow you to print each part in the best orientation for quality and reduce the risk of print failure. However, it will require more time for preparing the model for printing and post-processing work to assemble the parts. Bear in mind, that if you decide to separate the parts, it may still be necessary to print them with supports. It is also a better option if the model exceeds the printer's build volume.

To make the assembly easier, you can add alignment pins and holes to the parts to ensure they fit together correctly. Here is a very good tutorial on how to do it - [**How to cut STL models for 3D printing in Meshmixer**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tgc66TvEke4). You can also add alignment pins and holes right in Chitubox.

Both printing options have their pros and cons, and you should choose the one that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

### STL print speed is determined by height in Z

So to print your project, you should reduce Z height. In this case, your figurine can be placed with its height along the XY plane - lying on the back - and then drops its print time by roughly a factor of 8.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you should never print a figure like that upright as it A) takes too long and B) can cause problems with supports.

I would recommend that you cut it on two pieces. One with the legs and one with the body. This will cut your print time almost in half.

Next, tilt both parts backwards by at least 45 degrees. This will further reduce print time and will give you better supports as you can spread them out across a larger surface area while having a smaller surface area in contact with the FEP for each layer.

My printer ins an Elegoo Saturn. I use Chitubox.